# App Store Update not regonized

Tags: iphone, xcode, app-store, release

i just released a new Version for my App in the App Store.
On a second device where i had already the old Version running, i was checking for updates. It was not available. So i had to install the app again.
Someone with the same issue? Could not find something about this in google!

Comment: Hello, I have also same issue !! i have to search my app explicitly in app store . It should give me update badge ri8???? Bt seems like strange that when i install new version app it will overwrite with existing app so app id is not a problem... now dont know what to do as developer ??

Comment: i was waiting for about 15 hours and then the proper update appeared. But if you downloaded before the app was replaced with the newer version. i think the push notification for updates takes just some time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing check that, your new version is approved by Apple and it's live on App Store.
If the app is approved and new version is live on App Store, then check that it's region. For example, inside your device, you account is belongs to India, and your app is not available for that store then it will not display.

Please check it and let me know in case of any query.

Cheers.

Comment: it was approved and i could also see, that there was the new version, but it was just not appearing automatically during checking for updates. sorry if i was not so clear.

Comment: Have you also checked with Store? Means in your device, if store will be suppose India, and your app is not available in this store then it will not shown.

Comment: now its asking for an update on another device. it was just patience.